# Join two group_concat result

Tags: mysql, group-concatenation

this is the query:

```
$sql = "select pn.id, pn.purchased_number, pn.plan, pn.ring_to_group, 
        count(rtg.id) as totalGroups, 
        concat_ws(',', group_concat(rtg.group_name), group_concat(rtg.id)) as groupList
           from tbl_phone_numbers as pn
           left join tbl_rings_to_groups as rtg on rtg.user_id=pn.user_id
           where pn.user_id = ? and pn.status = ?";
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($this->userId, 'Y'));
```

that returns the result of `groupList` like `default,demo,1,2` but i want to get result something like :

`default:1,demo:2`

in **MYSQL** any suggestion??

Comment: try `group_concat(concat(rtg.group_name, ':', rtg.id)) as groupList`

Comment: @ypercube, thanks i get the expected result with `group_concat(concat_ws(':', rtg.group_name, rtg.id)) as groupList`, also tried yours and got the same result. Thanks again to responding.

Comment: @ypercube i want to close this question, so please reply in answer section so that this question also helpful to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse the order of the two functions, so the concatenation of `group_name` and `id` is done first - using either `CONCAT()` or `CONCAT_WS()` - and then the group concatenation:

```
GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT_WS(':', rtg.group_name, rtg.id) 
              ORDER BY rtg.id
              SEPARATOR ','                      -- the comma ',' is the default
            ) AS groupList
```